# PHP / MySQL Statement - Selecting record from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to write a query but not sure how to go about it.

Basically, i have a table with a column called auths, this keeps user id values of authorised users and is formatted as comma seperated as follows:

```
126,163,178
```

In another table are the 'usernames' and the id of that user is one of the values as above.

I want to echo out the username.

Can someone help me with this.

Cheers,

Comment: Can I inquire why you chose this table structure?

Comment: It was pre written by another developer

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor your database structure so you have a `users` table with the following fields:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  auth BOOL
);
```

There's no sense in hitting 2 tables if you can keep the information, which is clearly related, in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a connection table wht will have author_id and user_id fields, have script to extract those information from your comma separated field...

if this can not be rebuild consider use temp table

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, there is no way to split a string by a delimiter. You have to use two queries. The first query is to acquire all the IDs from the auths table. Then in your application, split the ID values by comma programmatically. The second query will select all rows from the 'usernames' table where the user id IN the list of IDs you have.